# DocuSign - Delete Envelope

Tags: python-3.x, docusignapi, webhooks

We're using the DocuSign SDK (version 3.3.0) and utilizing webhooks to receive the various envelope and recipient events.

Similar to DocuSign, we have given a option to delete an envelope in our application. Since there is no webhook notification once a envelope is moved to deleted bin. And also there is a field called deleted_date_time in get_envelope method (which provides the envelope details) and there is no status change, which are not updated once the envelope is being removed from the deleted bin.

Can anyone please help me in how to make sure the envelope has been removed from the deleted bin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no means to permanently delete and envelope or remove it from the recycle bin folder. You cannot do that from the DocuSign Web App either as far as I can tell.
Voiding an envelope is and deleting it is as good as it gets. There's no need to worry about it anymore.