# Docusign - Delete Envelope (From Signer Context)

Tags: python-3.x, docusignapi

We are using the DocuSign SDK (version 3.3.0) and utilizing webhooks to receive the various envelope and recipient events.

I am sending an envelope to a signer (who has account in our application, so that he can log in and sign the envelope). When the signer logs in and deletes the received envelope. The envelope is getting voided, as if the envelope was deleted by the sender. (since the envelope is in-process and delete API has no specific argument to tell either sender / signer is deleting it)

But in DocuSign process, if the envelope is deleted by the signer, it shows no effect (envelope is just moved to delete bin).

Can anyone please tell me, is there any API / possible way to delete the envelope from signer context in embedded signing?

Edit : Sorry if my question is not clear. My question is how can  i initiate envelop deletion as a recipient using DocuSign API, is there an option to pass the clientuserid or any other parameter and delete an envelop as recipient.

While its quite easy as a sender to delete an envelop using DocuSign API , I did not find any way to delete a envelop as recipient using docusign API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tharani, You already asked this - [DocuSign - Delete Envelope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63931911/docusign-delete-envelope/63946598#63946598), so I'll just answer again:

There's no means to permanently delete and envelope or remove it from the recycle bin folder. You cannot do that from the DocuSign Web App either as far as I can tell. Voiding an envelope is and deleting it is as good as it gets. There's no need to worry about it anymore.

Comment: Sorry if my question is not clear. My question is how can  i initiate envelop deletion as a recipient using DocuSign API, is there an option to pass the clientuserid or any other parameter and delete an envelop as recipient.

While its quite easy as a sender to delete an envelop using DocuSign API , I did not find any way to delete a envelop as recipient using docusign API.

Comment: To be clear, there is "deleting an envelope in the DocuSign Web App" and then there is setting an envelope to Voided status.  These are distinct and different operations, the first being a UI thing while the second is a change in envelope status.

When a sender cancels an envelope, they Void the envelope (web app or API).  
When a signer wishes to cancel the envelope, they choose to Decline to Sign the envelope via the menu options.  There is no API for doing that as a signer as this must be done by the person.

Comment: Recipients cannot delete an envelope as they do not control/own it and they can only either sign or reject it. This is a core design issue conceptually, not a technical limitation.